# Multiple negative z-index in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a dropdown menu with 4 menu categories. One, Two, Three & Four.
Each category have a negative z-index command.

One (z-index-1)
Two (z-index-2)
Three (z-index-2)
Four (z-index-2)

That way, zindex-1 is always in front (ΟΝΕ).

If I press menu Two, I want it to become z-index -1 and the rest to change automatically to -2 etc.
i.e

One (z-index-2)
Two (z-index-1)
Three (z-index-2)
Four (z-index-2)

I wonder , is there a better way to write this code? Thanks

[image]

```js
$('.one').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'z-index': '-1'
});

$('.two').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'z-index': '-2'
});

$('.three').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'z-index': '-2'
});

$('.four').css({
'position': 'absolute',
'z-index': '-2'
});
```

Comment: Probably you'd be better using classes here. Something along the way `hidden-menu` `shown-menu`. And flip the clases when you click a menu.

Comment: Why are you shifting items around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for starters -

```
$('.one,.two,.three,.four').click(function() { 
   $('.one,.two,.three,.four').css({position: 'absolute', 'z-index': '-2'});
   $(this).css('z-index', '-1'); 
})
```

But if you added your html, and actual purpose in doing that, I believe the answer will be much different.

Comment: yes but, what if I click on the button Three of Four? Any function or anything else that include all these 4 together? ie If I click One, Two Three or Four make it z-index -1 and others z-index -2  ..thanks

Comment: I changed the answer to match your comment.